# Client Server Looping causes broken pipe - C

Tags: c, client, pipe, infinite-loop

I have a simple Client and Server program in C, communicating via TCP. The client sends messages to the server and the server writes it to a file.

I need the client to loop indefinitely, until it reads an EOF character, and for the server to keep servicing the requests. However, at the moment I am getting issues with the looping. It works fine without any loops, but when I put a while(1) in the client the server services the first request fine but the second doesn't do anything and the third causes a broken pipe error. I think this is because the server closes the socket too early but I'm stuck on how to fix it.

Here's my Client program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define BUFFERLENGTH 256

/* displays error messages from system calls */
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[BUFFERLENGTH];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf (stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(1);
    }

    /* create socket */
    portno = atoi (argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error ("ERROR opening socket");

    /* enter connection data */
    server = gethostbyname (argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n"); // error message for when the provided hostname doesn't exist. 
        exit (1);
    }
    bzero ((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy ((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons (portno);

    /* connect to the server */
    if (connect (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error ("ERROR connecting");
while(1){
    /* prepare message */
    printf ("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero (buffer, BUFFERLENGTH);
    fgets (buffer, BUFFERLENGTH, stdin);

    /* send message */
    n = write (sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error ("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero (buffer, BUFFERLENGTH);

    /* wait for reply */
    n = read (sockfd, buffer, BUFFERLENGTH -1);
    if (n < 0) 
         error ("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf ("%s\n",buffer);

}
return 0;
}
```

And Server code:

```
/* A threaded server which uses TCP to communicate with clients.
       Passes the port number and a file name in as arguments.
       Receives log entries from the clients and writes them to the file. */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    #define BUFFERLENGTH 256

    /* displays error messages from system calls */
    void error(char *msg)
    {
        perror(msg);
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *file;
    int returnValue; 
    pthread_mutex_t mut; /* the lock */

    /* the procedure called for each request */
    void *processRequest (void *args) {
      int *newsockfd = (int *) args;
      char buffer[BUFFERLENGTH];
      int n, formed = 0;

      n = read (*newsockfd, buffer, BUFFERLENGTH -1);
      if (n < 0) 
        error ("ERROR reading from socket");

      printf ("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
      pthread_mutex_lock (&mut); /* lock exclusive access to variable isExecuted */

        //const char* string = "hello world";
        char buffer2[256];
        char* walker;
        int colon = 0;


        strcpy(buffer2,buffer);

    walker=buffer2;

    while(colon == 0){

        if(*walker == ':'){ // if it encounters a colon will successfully exit the loop.
            colon = 1;
        }
        if(*walker == '\0'){ // if it encounters the end of the string, will break the loop.
            break;
        }
        if(isalnum(*walker)){ // if it's not an alphanumeric character then it will break the loop, otherwise it will continue.
            walker++;
    } else {
    break;}

    }

    if(colon == 1){ // if the loop found a colon, then it will continue to search the rest of the string.
        while(*walker >= 32 && *walker<= 126){
                ++walker;
            if(*walker == '\n'){
                printf("Entry well formed.\n");
                fprintf(file,"%s",buffer); /*writes*/
                    fclose(file); /*done!*/ 
                formed = 1;
            }
            } 
    } else{
        perror("Entry not well formed.\n");
    }

      pthread_mutex_unlock (&mut); /* release the lock */

    if(formed==1){
      n = sprintf (buffer, "Message received and written to file.\n");
    }else{
        n = sprintf (buffer, "Message received but was not well formed and was not written to file.\n");
    }
      /* send the reply back */
      n = write (*newsockfd, buffer, BUFFERLENGTH);
      if (n < 0) 
        error ("ERROR writing to socket");

      close (*newsockfd); /* important to avoid memory leak */  
      free (newsockfd);

      returnValue = 0;  /* cannot guarantee that it stays constant */
      pthread_exit (&returnValue);
    }



    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
         socklen_t clilen;
         int sockfd, portno;
         char buffer[BUFFERLENGTH];
         struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
         pthread_t *server_thread;
         int result;


         if (argc < 3) {
             fprintf (stderr,"ERROR, arguments: port filename.\n"); /* Error message for if there isn't enough arguments. */
             exit(1);
         }


         /* create socket */
         sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
         if (sockfd < 0) 
            error("ERROR opening socket");
         bzero ((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
         portno = atoi(argv[1]);
         serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
         serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
         serv_addr.sin_port = htons (portno);

         /* bind it */
         if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                  sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
                  error("ERROR on binding");

         /* ready to accept connections */
         listen (sockfd,5);
         clilen = sizeof (cli_addr);

         /* now wait in an endless loop for connections and process them */
         while (1) {

          file = fopen(argv[2], "a");
          if (file == NULL) {
             printf("I couldn't open results.txt for writing.\n");
             exit(0);
          }
           int *newsockfd; /* allocate memory for each instance to avoid race condition */
           pthread_attr_t pthread_attr; /* attributes for newly created thread */

           newsockfd  = malloc (sizeof (int));
           if (!newsockfd) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
         exit (1);
           }
           /* waiting for connections */
           *newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                  (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                  &clilen);
           if (*newsockfd < 0) 
         error ("ERROR on accept");
           bzero (buffer, BUFFERLENGTH);

         /* create separate thread for processing */
         server_thread = malloc (sizeof (pthread_t));
         if (!server_thread) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for thread!\n");
         exit (1);
           }

         if (pthread_attr_init (&pthread_attr)) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Creating initial thread attributes failed!\n");
         exit (1);
         }

         if (pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&pthread_attr, !PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)) {
             fprintf (stderr, "setting thread attributes failed!\n");
         exit (1);
         }
         result = pthread_create (server_thread, &pthread_attr, processRequest, (void *) newsockfd);
           if (result != 0) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Thread creation failed!\n");
         exit (1);
           }


         }
         return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you server code has been pasted badly and contains several copies of `main()` mixed up.

In the server, you call `accept()` to receive the client connection.  You then create a thread to handle the connection.  This thread handles just one message and exits, yet it is supposed to be servicing all messages from the client until the client has had enough.

So you need to put a loop in the server thread to allow it to handle multiple messages.

Note that when I ran your server, the first message, handled by the thread, was received correctly (message read "hello") but was reported to be badly formed (message `Entry not well formed.`). Running on OS-X.

Note also that the line:

```
if (pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&pthread_attr, !PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)) {
```

should not have the '!' in front of the constant PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED.

Comment: Sorry, have corrected the badly pasted server code now.
The well formed/not well formed is part of the program, strings need to follow a grammar to be written to a file.